# why my onClick works only after two click

Tags: android, onclick, android-timepicker

I am having 4 buttons in my activity and all the buttons have same action .So I have defined oclick in Xml.Button click should open Date picker dialog.But my date picker opens only after two click in my Samsung 
S2(Android 4.0.4). But all other device which its working fine .

1.Samsung Star 4.1

2.Videocon 2.3

XML onclick declaration

```
     <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:onClick="AddTime"
           />
```

AddTime Method in Activity

```
   public void AddTime(View v)
{
  Log.e("Test", "Button Clicked");//On evey click I am getting this log
    showDialog(1);//The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated

}

  @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);
}

  private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker arg0, int hourofDay, int min) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        hour=hourofDay;
        minute=min;
        String _24HourTime;
            }
};
```

Comment: can you log inside the method and try if it will take 2 clicks

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin on very click I am getting log message .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `showDialog` is `deprecated` you can't really rely on it, I would recommend you just directly create the dialog from a method.

```
public void showTimePickerDialog()
{
    TimePickerDialog s4 = new TimePickerDialog(this, null, 1, 1,false);
    s4.show();
}
```

And call it in your `onClick` method

```
public void AddTime(View v)
{
   showTimePickerDialog();
}
```

Comment: but Its working for other devices ..One earlier version and  one later version.. Then also let me try

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz why use a deprecated method when there are better alternatives?

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz I would recommend to check the api of device if it is less than **api 12** then use the `showDialog ` else use the `showTimePickerDialog`

Comment: super ,its working..Actually I thought if its working for Android 4.1 then definitely it should work for 4.0..But I was wrong as you said we can't really rely on deprecated methods.So it may work on some case and may not..